# yii 'Trying to get property of non-object' on server but not on my machine

Tags: php, yii, wampserver

I m newbie in php. I had developed a small web application using Yii on wampserver (win7 64bit). Then i deploy the code on server win XP (32bit). I m getting error,`“Trying to get property of non-object”` at view. I had figured the cause of error. I m displaying values from database and some of the values are NULL. I resolved the error by initializing the variable with default value. Now, application is running smoothly.

My question is when variables were not initialized, why I was not getting error on my laptop  but on server?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the error reporting was disabled on your development system, you should receive an error when an uninitialized variable is used. 
 Check that the error reporting was not disabled, or **@** was not used; if that's not the case, the variable might have been initialized in a separate file before being called; verify that all the files on required were hosted on the server. 
 
Hope it helps.

On an unrelated note, if you are using PHP and MySQL, it makes much sense to use Linux (any flavor) as your OS, and Apache as your web server; they are built and optimized to go perfectly with PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

in case if variable is no initialized, or object not created and try to fetch the property of the object error will be shown both on server and local machine.for defensive coding perspective check before accessing property of object set or not.